# Как реализовать приоритетность в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview

Мне нужно реализовать функцию приоритетности. То есть как оно работает, при добавлении заметок пользователь сможет выбрать важность этой заметки, и соответственно самая важная заметка будет располагаться в самом верху RecyclerView, а самая низкая по приоритетности, в самом низу. Как это сделать? Если есть источники поделитесь пожалуйста. Долго искал, не могу найти ответ [image: Здесь на картинке показана возможность выбрать важность заметки]

Answer (score 1):

В модель заметки добавьте поле `priority`. Перед предоставлением RecyclerView.Adapter выполните сортировку элементов списка `notes.sortBy { it.priority }`. Значение приоритета лучше сделать численным, вы можете зарание задать константы типа `val const MAX = 3`
Но я бы сделал перечисление

```
enum Priority(val code: Int) {
   MAX(1),
   MIN(0)
}
```

Comment: И как сделать так чтобы важная заметка располагалась вверху RecyclerView? Как-то поверхностно вы прошлись...

Comment: @mr.hinkal05 я вам это и рассказал. При предоставлении адаптеру списка элементов, recyclerView отобразит их точно в таком порядке, как они находились в списке. Получается достаточно лишь правильно отсортировать этот список, что бы приоритетные заметки были первыми. Возможно я вас запутал котлином. Посмотрите ответ Barmaley ниже, там джава.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему все достаточно просто, допустим у вас есть ваш адаптер заданий (Task):

```
public class TasksAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // blah-blah, пропускаем декларацию ViewHolder и т.д.

    private List<Task> mTasks;
}
```

По сути вам надо сделать сортировку `List<Task>` по полю `priority`, которое надо завести.

Что-то навроде такого:

```
Collections.sort(mTasks, new Comparator<Task>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Task lTask, Task rTask) {
            return lTask.getPriority() > rTask.getPriority() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
```

После чего надо не забыть вызвать на адаптере `notifyDatasetChanged()`